# CSS stop element from having greater height than parent

Tags: css, positioning

I approximatley this structure

`<div>
    <div id='1'> </div>
    <div id='2'> </div>
</div>`

I want to make it so that when div 1's content becomes too large for it and div 2 to fit in the main div, it will get a scrollbar and not push anything off the bottom of the parent div.

How can I do this in CSS?

EDIT:

the parent div (or rather, its parent) has a set height.  and at this point setting overflow : scroll on div1 just causes it to go beyond the bottom with a scrollbar on the side.

Comment: I was under the impression -bearing in mind I've not tested the theory- that however much content you have in div#1 (and div#2) the parent div will expand to accommodate, unless you've defined an explicit width on that parent?

Comment: Div IDs cannot begin with numbers, so you may encounter bugs when testing this that have nothing to do with the usefulness of the solution

Comment: yeah, it was just for illustration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need overflow: scroll on div 1. And also you need to somehow fix such a value of its height that the div will need a scrollbar after reaching this value. Should be no problem if you have a fixed height or max-height on your parent div.

EDIT

Check this out: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/overflow.html.
It seems (unfortunately) that you nevertheless need a value for your div 1's height. I figured out max-height will do, too.
And, by the way, for the scrollbars to appear only when necessary, you need overflow: auto.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
overflow:scroll
```

in your CSS on div1.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I tried this and it is not working.  Somehow div 1 is not inheriting a max height from the parent

Comment: See neutrino's comment. YOu may also have to set a fixed height for div 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overflow setting:

```
#id
{

   overflow: scroll;

}
```